# Alignment of Google ReCaptcha v2 bootstrap

Tags: c#, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am wondering if anyone could help with the issue that I am having. I have a form in which, I am putting ReCaptcha v2. No matter what I try I can not get ReCaptcha to be in the correct alignment with the rest of the form which would be directly underneath the text boxes with writing to the left. I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this issuse

The Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    div.g-recaptcha {

        left: 0px;
        width: 304px;
    }
</style>

<div class="form-group">
  Are You Human
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div align="center" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

An image of what is happening.

[image]

Richards Approach

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not styled your label.  Put it inside a col-md-2 to push the content over.  You also need to remove the `align="center"`, and possibly need to add form-control-static to the class of the captcha.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Are You Human</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-control-static g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, the alignment is off with your approach. I will add an image of the output to the end of my post.

Comment: Updated - you've got an align=center in there too which is probably messing things up.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue.